# How to display map on Blackberry by using Kony Studio?

Tags: javascript, cross-platform, temenos-quantum

I am new to Kony Studio. I have to display Google map on mobile by using kony Studio API.I tried and Its working fine on Android mobile.But On blackberry,It's not working on blackberry.Please give me some solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Without some more information, hard to diagnose, but take a look at the Kony Map Widget documentation; there are some specific steps you need to follow to setup the map widget in Blackberry, and some Blackberry configurations that need to be set for the map to be able to test it in the emulator.  Take a look here: [Kony doc Map Reference](http://docs.kony.com/KonyLibrary/#../Subsystems/Widget_User_Guide/Content/Map.htm?TocPath=Kony%20Development%20Cloud%7CWidget%20User%20Guide%7CMap%7C_____0)

Answer (score 0):

Following the above recommendation I found the below simple sample.

```
enter code here

function onPinClickCallBck(map)
{
    alert("Some Message");

var mapBasicConf = {
                        id: "map1",
                        provider:constants.MAP_PROVIDER_GOOGLE, 
                        mapKey:"0z5UtaSPUYj42f5qX0VAwmDGLX39Qxgbtcra0TA", 
                        defaultPinImage: "kmpin.png", 
                        isVisible:true, onPinClick:onPinClickCallBck
                    };


var mapLayoutConf = {
                        margin:[20,40,50,20], 
                        containerWeight:100, 
                        widgetAlignment:constants.WIDGET_ALIGN_BOTTOM_LEFT,padding:    [10,10,10,10], 
                        hExpand:false, 
                        vExpand:false
                    };
var mapPSPConf = {
                    mode: constants.MAP_VIEW_MODE_HYBRID, 
                    showCurrentLocation:constants.MAP_VIEW_SHOW_CURRENT_LOCATION_AS_PIN
                };
var map = new kony.ui.Map(mapBasicConf,mapLayoutConf,mapPSPConf);



enter code here
```

I hope it is helpful.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe ***BIS (Blackberry Internet Services)*** on the BB device to see map widget functioning properly.